# Saving after using fet.setFeatureId in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

By using the following code, I want to change the id of the line when saving the line. But the setFeatureId command, gives a  false when doing the commitChanges().

Any idea how to change the id?

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString", layerName, "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
vl.startEditing()
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline( [[ QgsPoint(x3,y3),QgsPoint(x4,y4) ]] ))
fet.setFeatureId(10001)
pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
vl.commitChanges()
```

---

I added an attribute with the id i wanted instead of changing the existing id.

Comment: I'm not sure you should be setting the ID your self. Leave that up to the provider to do.  Just call addFeatures then you can get the id back using fet.id()